# Get connection variable from a class sent with a form

Tags: php

I have a problem with get the connection variable for open a database connection.

**This my code in html**

```
 <form action="password.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="current" placeholder="Contraseña Actual..." />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="new" placeholder="Nueva Contraseña..." />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm" placeholder="Repetir Nueva Contraseña..." />
            </div>
            </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="hidden" name="q" value="proofQueries">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Cambiar</button>
        </form>
```

**While the code of my class php**

```
$settings = new Datasettings();

require_once('../config.php'); // file of connection of PDO
$conexion = new Conexion();


if(isset($_POST['q'])){ // get the name from html form for go to a function of this class

    $settings->$_POST['q']($conexion);
}

class Datasettings {

    function __construct(){
       session_start();
        if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){

            header('location:mystyle.css');  

        }
    }

    function proofQueries($conexion){
    }


... other functions....
```

Could change the model how I call a the function? How I could make it?

Comment: `$settings->$_POST['q']($conexion);` does not seem like a good plan...

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is not working with what you have?

Comment: I tried call the function with a form because I had to send $conexion PDO variable to a class with a determinate function.  I found a way, Now I send a form with its action="" and get the data with "isset".  Is there another way of send parameters to a function?

Comment: Answer might be easy one but the real difficulty is understanding the question .

Answer (score 0):

I assume by this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['q'])){ // get the name from html form for go to a function of this class
  $settings->$_POST['q']($conexion);
}
```

And submitting the hidden form field called `q` with value `proofQueries`, you are trying to call `$settings->proofQueries($conexion)`. This is an **extremely bad idea**.

You are effectively executing code that comes directly from client side, which is a **HUGE** vulnerability risk.

It seems like a strange approach to begin with to specify the function client side, and then execute it in PHP (i.e. server side). Why specifying the `q` value at all, instead of just explicitly doing `$settings->proofQueries($conexion)` in PHP?

If you somehow *must* specify the function to be called client side, do something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['q'])){ // get member function from submitted form
  $f = $_POST['q'];
  if ($f=='proofQueries') {
    $settings->proofQueries($conexion);
  }
  else {
    die("Nope");
  }
}
```

Or if you have multiple possible functions, explicitly filter them with a whitelist to make **absolutely 100% sure** that ONLY the function names you decide can be called:

```
if(isset($_POST['q'])){ // get member function from submitted form
  $f = $_POST['q'];
  $allowedFunctions = array('proofQueries','doSomething','otherFunction');
  if (in_array($f,$allowedFunctions)) {
    $settings->$f($conexion);
  }
  else {
    die("Nope");
  }
}
```

But again, it seems like a strange approach alltogether. You should not specify server side specific implementation details through client side.